# compare two multidimension and associative arrays and get the difference

Tags: php, arrays

I need to compare two arrays like this

```
// currently in our database
$firstArr = array(
        ["id"=>1, "another_id"=>1],
        ["id"=>2, "another_id"=>4],
        ["id"=>5, "another_id"=>9]
);

// currently fetched from csv-files
$secondArr = array(
        ["id"=>6, "another_id"=>3],
        ["id"=>2, "another_id"=>7],
        ["id"=>1, "another_id"=>1]
);
```

The first array represents the data that is currently in our database, meanwhile the second one  represents the data that is delivered from an `csv`-file.

In order to not delete the whole data from the database, I need to compare the two array's. If the `csv`-file offers data that is not in the database, I want to input these data sets. If the database includes data that is not in the `csv`-file, I want to remove them from the database.

I come up with a solution that works for a small amount of data in the arrays:

```
$new_to_database = array();
foreach($secondArr AS $arr){
    $in_database = array_filter(array_map(function($el) use ($arr){
        if($el['id'] == $arr['id'] && $el['another_id'] == $arr['another_id']){
            return $el;
        }
    }, $firstArr));

    if(count($in_database) === 0){
        $new_to_database[] = $arr;
    }               
}

var_dump($new_to_database);   // input later on
// array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(6) ["another_id"]=> int(3) } [1]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> int(2) ["another_id"]=> int(7) } }
```

The problem is that each array includes round about 5000 data sets. As a result the script takes far to long and I get the error that the execution time of 360 seconds is exceeded.

How can I solve this? I guess the algorithm should be way more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can index each array by the `id` and then compute the difference in the keys:

```
// Get items that are in CSV but not in database
$new = array_diff_key(array_column($csv, null, 'id'), array_column($db, null, 'id'));

// Get items that are in database but not in CSV
$del = array_diff_key(array_column($db, null, 'id'), array_column($csv, null, 'id'));
```

Here's a [DEMO](https://3v4l.org/43okQ) using two simple arrays of 50,000 items each.

That's short and sweet but you may not want to run the `array_column` multiple times:

```
$csv = array_column($csv, null, 'id');
$db  = array_column($db, null, 'id');

// Get items that are in CSV but not in database
$new = array_diff_key($csv, $db);

// Get items that are in database but not in CSV
$del = array_diff_key($db, $csv);
```

To compare the entire array contents (this will work if you add more than just `id` and `another_id`), you can map each array and serialize into a string representation and compare.  Note that the order of the elements matters as well:

```
// Get items that are in CSV but not in database
$new = array_map('unserialize',
                 array_diff(array_map('serialize', $csv), array_map('serialize', $db)));

// Get items that are in database but not in CSV        
$del = array_map('unserialize',
                 array_diff(array_map('serialize', $db), array_map('serialize', $csv)));
```

On the DEMO site this one worked for 40,000 array items but not 50,000.  This will depend on your resources and `php.ini` settings.

---

There's also an [array_intersect_key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) and [array_intersect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) if you want to see what is the same in each array.

Comment: Thanks for your fast respond @AbraCadaver. This works great if we only check for the `id` attribute, but I need to check for the combination of `id` and `another_id`.Is it possible to add this to your code?

Comment: Added another option to compare the full arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a lot of loops. `foreach`, `array_filter` and `array_map` use a lot of time.

```
$new_to_database = array_udiff($secondArr, $firstArr, function ($s, $f) {
    if ($s['id'] == $f['id'] && $s['another_id'] == $f['another_id']) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
});
```

This gives the results you need with less iterations.